# Align Icon and text right next to each other for proper sho display - help! :(

Tags: css, styles

I need help with the following code. I am SUPER NEW and just learned html and css. Well lets say I am still learning. I want this icon displayed and right next to it the text. The problem is that the camera (icon) is not properly aligned to the next. The Icon is a little bit of the line from the text. I want it centered. I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

```html
<html>

<body>
  
<p>

<h2>   

<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAYAAACqaXHeAAACR0lEQVR4nO3aP2sTcRzH8aOhRDqIo4h/QBEnwcnBR+BSELQo6KwPQR+AqJsUHHRToSilurj4BBzcBC0q0oqLS2m1FRVEfTkkxSOkzf353V3S/N6QLb9PPt937i7J75IkkUgkEolEIinQxiU8wRLWuo8lLOAi2sOaXwqcw0eDWcbZYcsvDFqYzVCsl9toNZ0fQsCdAuU2mW06v+zwZ0qUg7+Ybiq/7PC7ZDsnB7Gsz4Wr6vwQAi4EKLfJTN35IQQ8Dlhwru78EAI+BCz4ru78EAK+BSy4UXd+FBBAwPuABd/WnR9CwFzAgg/rzg8hYOw/BieFOUzf6POdver8UBLG96twquSNEgWvN50fQsB4/xxOFR3PDZGekm2dq/cDLOJn97GI+ziv/JZYZflFCh3U2YtbyfDONM2Kzl7ikZIz78WjBAew2uREBVnF/gKDT+AKvkCiY3NUmc85/HG8SAck2Gikehi+Zhx8Cjfxqzcgqb1yYDIMP4PPW66vr2o1bDP4ITwbuL7yhhXTZ/AWruJ7pvWVtquBnuFP4lWu9XleoAmy9MNu3MOfPMPvCAE4rXNTtRA7QUApooAoIAqIAqKAKCAKiAJGVkD3OVO4hd/BBQw7PbJO4GWu9dXUqo8+R8wELmM90/pK29XANqfOPswPXF99xWrJcA2Zxqct18t4qAwpWTdF9+CuPvsFCZ7W3TogC1kEpEScwut0QIJjOv/UHjXWcDSPgK6ESVzDD7qnkP+3xkbhHsG6MLfGDuN5mYxIJBKJRCKjzT8YxRMTHEdMlgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/> 
  This a camera 
  
  </h2>

  </p> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you upload what you have so far to JSFiddle, so we can help you more :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `position: relative;` and the `top: $px;` or `bottom: $px;` properties to the image (where $ is the number of pixels you want the image to space from the top or bottom). Like this:

```
img {position: relative; top: 2px;}
```

It's pretty easy, but beginners miss it sometimes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin. It worked I just need another hint. My text is colliding with the pictures... here check the webpage I am working on right now. Sorry its in german litestudios.de

Comment: Well... it's pretty hard to fix it in this case, but I'll try to explain.

(1) You'll have to add a `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to the H2 in order do vertically center the text, and add a `padding-left` to add some space for the image, like this: `padding: 20px 0 20px 70px;`
(2) Remove the `&nbsp;` code before the text, so it'll be perfectly aligned.
(3) Add a `position: relative` property to the H2.
(4) Change the image's `position: relative` property to `position: absolute` and add `top: 0; left: 0;`

I think that's it. If it's still not working, e-mail me: kevinthomas.dev@hotmail.com